# Siri giving out incorrect info

Tags: siri

I have Verizon and Siri is giving me a fax number for a location rather than a phone number. My friend has AT & T and it displays the phone number. Does it matter which carrier is used? Can I correct this (it is my place of business)

Comment: It does not matter which carrier is used. Could you show a screenshot of the information displayed on both the phones ?

Answer (score 1):

Siri pulls information from your contacts. Make sure that the information in your contacts is accurate.